# Restart Akka Actor System after terminated

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, shutdown-hook

We have an Akka http app with approx. 100+ API and 15+ Actors. After `Http.bindAndHandle(routes, host, port)` I have terminated ActorSystem.

```
Http().bindAndHandle(corsHandler(routes), "0.0.0.0", 9090/*, connectionContext = https*/)
sys.addShutdownHook(actorSystem.terminate())
```

So, I don't want to stop my application. So, My questions are:

1. Does actorsystem needs to terminate compulsory?
2. Does my application stop working after terminating actorsystem?
3. What if user hits API after actorsystem is terminated? Does it Restart again to handle API requests?

So, what do I need to do if I want my application always listening to client requests.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason that your actor is getting terminated? And why don’t you use the supervision strategy to resume or restart your actor

Comment: Thanks @Raman for quick response. Is it needed to terminate system? I don't know when it will terminate.

Comment: Thanks i will check supervision stategy to resume or restart..let me know links if you want me to follow pleased.

Comment: So it will be terminated if and only if some error occurs!! Right then use the supervision strategy and as soon as you got some error propagated to the supervisor just restart the actor it’s simple so your application will be listening your request

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/supervision.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for fault tolerance in your application. As the actor system is going to be terminated in situation of some error or when we explicitly force it to terminate. You have to use supervision strategy for your application to be fault tolerant.  Please look into these links

> https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fault-tolerance.html
>   https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/supervision.html

Comment: Thanks i will definitely look into this

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a shutdown hook is to allow an orderly shut down of the application *when the JVM is about to shutdown*. It's not necessarily required in all circumstances, but an orderly shutdown could be useful if your ActorSystem wants to release resources in an orderly manner, or signal to other nodes in a cluster that it's being shut down.

When the actor system has terminated, there will be no more actors to handle HTTP requests, because actors cannot exist without a running actor system to be part of. So no, if your user hits the API after the actor system has terminated, the actor system will not be restarted, because instead the request will simply be rejected (connection refused or something).

You can't avoid that happening *in your code* because a JVM shutdown cannot be cancelled.

However, the good news is, you can avoid it *at the infrastructure level* using various operational techniques, e.g. blue-green deployments with a HTTP load balancer can support downtime-free upgrades of stateless applications.

Comment: Thanks Robin. 
 i have initialised actorsyatem multiple times. Like in my services i need implicit val of executors and actorsystems. So, i have initilised Actorsyatem 4 times like this in my classes:


  private implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  private implicit val executor: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
  private implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

Does this impact on my application performance. Because my application is hanging after 1 to 2 days running.
I terminated only one actorsystem as said above.

Comment: Is these actor systems taking all resources of server??

Comment: It shouldn't do. But that sounds like a completely different question. I suggest you ask a new question on Stackoverflow "Why is my Akka application hanging after 1 to 2 days?"